# Github shows that my commits have been pushed by 2 authors: me and me

Tags: git, github

GitHub shows that my commits have been pushed by 2 authors: me and me.

How can I turn it off?
That is, how can I avoid seeing "me" and "me" (twice my GitHub account) as "authors" of a commit?

Comment: Please post the output you're seeing, your question is unclear.

Comment: Turn off what exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, make sure this is authorship, not "author" and "committer".

If we are talking about two authors (as seen in the picture below) ,then this recent, since GitHub only announced it a few days ago (January 2018):
"[Commit together with co-authors](https://github.com/blog/2496-commit-together-with-co-authors)"

> To add co-authors to a commit, just add one or more "Co-authored-by" trailers to the end of the commit message:
>
> ```
> Commit message
>
> Co-authored-by: Joel Califa <602352+califa@users.noreply.github.com>
> Co-authored-by: Matt Clark <44023+mclark@users.noreply.github.com>
> ```
>
> Include your trailers at the end of your commit message, and have at least one line of white space before them.

See the [official documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors/).

In your case, that means any commit with multiple "`Co-authored by`" would be displayed that way:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/602352/35053024-b818ee72-fbb1-11e7-93f8-11baf411f1c1.gif]

> How can I turn it off?

Make sure you don't have any `Co-authored-by` field in your commit message trailer.

If you don't, [report that to GitHub support](https://github.com/contact), as it is most likely a bug resulting from their recent feature described above.

Answer (score 37):

its happens when your local Git configuration doesn't match with your Github account.

you can check this by:

`git config --global user.email`

to change your email configuration

`git config --global user.email "your email"`

Comment: Sometimes it's the local repository config, (not global): check git config user.email

Comment: 4 years later, but thanks - my commit graph was looking anemic and I couldn't figure out why and then I noticed the two names. My email had changed, making this change was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Coming from a [duplicate of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65651979/what-does-this-co-commit-in-github-mean?noredirect=1), the steps I have taken to fix this were (in the specific case of [GitExtensions](http://gitextensions.github.io/) and misconfiguration of my GitHub account).

#### In my GitHub account

[image]

#### In GitExtensions

Go to `Tools` → `Settings` and set the committer details there:

[image]

IN `Commit` (new window) → `Options`, you should have no Author set:

[image]

With this, further commits will be coming exclusively from the committer

**A special thanks to @jonrsharpe and @MahdiAryayi for the pointers to the explanation.**