# What does this co-commit in GitHub mean?

Tags: git, github

I pushed a local repo to GitHub (https://github.com/wsw70/meross-local-mqtt) and I see that the committer(s) are:

[image]

I am a single developer for this script and nobody ever saw it before (it is the first public push).

- `wsw70` is my account on GitHub
- `w` does not look familiar

When pushing the code, I forced an account so that it matches the one on GitHub (in GitExtensions)

[image]

Further pushes also hold this strange co-commit signature.

**Where does this come from?** (and how to fix it so that only my GitHub account is in the commits? (it is OK if it is only in the future ones, never mind for the first two))

In GitExtensions, only `wsw70` is seen as the committer:

[image]

Comment: It means you have something like "signed-off-by" in your commit messages: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1962094/3001761, https://github.blog/2018-01-29-commit-together-with-co-authors/

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51300050/9191712

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thank you. I believe that the "Author" functionality of GitExtensions adds the authorship, in addition to the configured committer details (which I thought would be overwritten). I found relevant information in my profile - if you would not mind to bootsrap an answer, i would gladly accept it and provide the information needed to configure the commit correctly (including what to change in GitHib)

Comment: I'd suggest putting an answer relating to the GitExtensions configuration onto the post @MahdiAryayi linked, so the information is all in one place.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: OK, I will do that and forcefully close this one as duplicate. Thanks again

Comment: @MahdiAryayi: Thank you - this is it. I will update the answer you pointed to with my findings.

Comment: By the way, something of the form `name <email>` is nominally incorrect: it should be `name <email@whatever>`. That is, the `@host.dom.ain` part of the email address is required. Not everything checks for this, so Git allows the email part without a host/domain part, but it's good to use the whole email address.